# Square brackets after function call

Tags: kotlin

In the [PagingWithNetworkSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/PagingWithNetworkSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/paging/pagingwithnetwork), in the [RedditActivity.kt](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/e732a397ee0601488e66d74ee184f296b7528768/PagingWithNetworkSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/paging/pagingwithnetwork/reddit/ui/RedditActivity.kt#L78) on the [line 68](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/e732a397ee0601488e66d74ee184f296b7528768/PagingWithNetworkSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/paging/pagingwithnetwork/reddit/ui/RedditActivity.kt#L68) is a function that contains another function call followed by [square brackets and the class type](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/e732a397ee0601488e66d74ee184f296b7528768/PagingWithNetworkSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/paging/pagingwithnetwork/reddit/ui/RedditActivity.kt#L78) (line 78):

```
private fun getViewModel(): SubRedditViewModel {
    return ViewModelProviders.of(this, object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            val repoTypeParam = intent.getIntExtra(KEY_REPOSITORY_TYPE, 0)
            val repoType = RedditPostRepository.Type.values()[repoTypeParam]
            val repo = ServiceLocator.instance(this@RedditActivity)
                    .getRepository(repoType)
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return SubRedditViewModel(repo) as T
        }
    })[SubRedditViewModel::class.java]
}
```

What does this exactly do? Automatically cast to that type? (it's not an array/list to suppose it calls `get`)

Can you bring an example where this is useful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That code might look strange, but it's really just a way of calling [`get()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.html#get(java.lang.Class)). This would be just as valid, but slightly more verbose:

```
private fun getViewModel(): SubRedditViewModel {
    return ViewModelProviders.of(this, object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            // ...
        }
    }).get(SubRedditViewModel::class.java)
}
```

Comment: So it is actually just another plain `get` call?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the link to the documentation. The previous link pointed to the Java version. I suggest taking a look at the Kotlin version. Another way for you to see this is by cloning the repository and navigating to the declaration: 1. Put your cursor to the right of the closing bracket `]`. 2. Go to `Navigate` → `Declaration` (⌘B).